# Update multiple documents with same property in NEST Client- Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-net

I have an update query which modifies only a single document. But I need to pass multiple documents as input and update them.

Previous code is as follows.

```
 var clientProvider = new ElasticClientProvider();
 var response = await clientProvider.Client.UpdateAsync<UserModel>(UserId, d => d
            .Index("user_index")
            .Type("user")
            .Script(script => script
                .Source("ctx._source.isActive = false"))
            );
```

In this I want to pass multiple user objects so that I can assign the same property to multiple documents at the same time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use UpdateByQuery (good news, you need to pass a script but you already got it!)

You have an example here: 
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/src/Tests/Tests/Document/Multiple/UpdateByQuery/UpdateByQueryApiTests.cs